# CustomUser object has no attribute 'method' Django 3.0

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I'm making a login view using login() with this import `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login`. The documentation says that login takes two arguments but when I use `login(request, user)` after doing `user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)` but it tells me that `login()` take one positional argument but got 2. When I use `login(user)` it tells me `CustomUser object has no attribute 'method'`

Error when using `login(request, user)`

```
TypeError at /user_accounts/login

login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

view

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'username or password not correct')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'user_accounts/login.html')
```

template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password">
        </p>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

url

```
url(r'^user_accounts/login', account_views.login, name="login"),
```

Comment: You've called your view `login` which is shadowing the login function you imported. Call it something else.

Comment: That worked, thank you. Really should have realized that. Thank you again